# ECI position and velocity from angular velocity

Tags: orbital-mechanics, propagation, eci

I need help with an orbital mechanics issue that I cannot figure out.

I have the initial ECI position and velocity ($r_{vec},v_{vec}$) of a certain satellite. Through them, the angular velocity, the radius and the instantaneous speed are computed according to the following formulas:
$$
r = ||r_{vec}|| \\
\dot{r} = \frac{r_{vec} \cdot v_{vec}}{r} \\
\dot{\theta} = \frac{||r_{vec} \times v_{vec}||}{r^2}
$$

At this point, $r,\dot{r},\dot{\theta}$ are used as state variables to propagate the satellite by integrating the following differential equations:
$$
\frac{dr}{dt}=\dot{r} \\
\frac{d\dot{r}}{dt}= r\dot{\theta}^2-\frac{\mu}{r^2} \\
\frac{d\dot{\theta}}{dt}=-2\dot{r}\frac{\theta}{r} 
$$

At the end of the integration process, I have the profiles of $r,\dot{r},\dot{\theta}$ in time, but not the ones of $r_{vec},v_{vec}$. is there a way to get back from the propagated $r,\dot{r},\dot{\theta}$ to the ECI position and velocity vectors? I'm supposed to get them back, but I cannot understand how to do that.

Thank you!